# Arrange 3 iframes - 1 main left / 2 sharing the right side - one top, one bottom

Tags: html, iframe, responsive-design

I am a newbie to coding and only picked up the basics so far. I want to arrange 3 iframes in a box that is 3/4 of the screen width (1/4 is sidebar)...not sure if that's even relevant.

I want the 3 iframes to share the box having one big on the left side (using 50% of the box, but 100% in height) and the 2 other ones sharing the right side - one being on the top, one on the bottom (= sharing 50% of the box on the right and each having 50% space in height).

I took this project over from another person and this is the code they used but it doesn't adjust properly to different screen sizes.

```
    <div style="margin: 0 -15px;">
    <div class="fusion-two-third fusion-layout-column alignleft video-left-content" style="padding: 0 15px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GfYl-aUr4OU" width="100%" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    <div class="fusion-one-third fusion-layout-column alignright video-right-content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 15px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5njYzmU_UtQ" width="100%" height="152" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    <div class="fusion-one-third fusion-layout-column alignright video-right-content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 15px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UcGv7lrperw" width="100%" height="152" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Would be awesome if someone could help me out with this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking?

```css
.section {
  height: 480px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

fusion-two-third {
  order: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.fusion-one-third {
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.fusion-one-third.one { order: 2; }
.fusion-one-third.two { order: 3; }
```

```html
<div class="section" style="margin: 0 -15px;">
    <div class="fusion-two-third fusion-layout-column alignleft video-left-content" style="padding: 0 15px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GfYl-aUr4OU" width="100%" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    <div class="fusion-one-third one fusion-layout-column alignright video-right-content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 15px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5njYzmU_UtQ" width="100%" height="152" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    <div class="fusion-one-third two fusion-layout-column alignright video-right-content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 15px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UcGv7lrperw" width="100%" height="152" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    </div>
```